# Do I need to call RDOMail.Save after setting a value to RDOMail.Fields?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I'm using Redemption to interact with Outlook emails in C#. Do I need to call `RDOMail.Save` after setting a value to `RDOMail.Fields`?

```
rdoMail.Fields["MyProperty"] = "MyValue";
rdoMail.Save(); // not sure if this is necessary
```

During my testing, it seems that even If I don't call the save method, my custom property value was able to be loaded out later by accessing `rdoMail.Fields["MyProperty"]` again. But I can't be sure that this is 100% the case. Outlook always seems a bit moody to me :P

I'd also like to know if this custom property value would be persisted if I save the email to a .msg file using Outlook.

Comment: How is RDOMail object retrieved?

Comment: It's mostly retrieved via `GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject` and occasionally via `GetMessageFromID`. Sounds like there are differences between the 2?

Comment: Yes, in case of GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject  you are sharing the message with OOM and OOM most likely calls Save, right? GetMessageFromID gives you a completely independent message, so it is your responsibility to call Save.

Comment: I'm not an expert of the OOM, I had no idea that it would call `Save` automatically. Because in my code, even it gets the `RDOMail` from an existing `MailItem` there is no code to call neither `RDOMail.Save` nor `MailItem.Save` and my custom property value still gets persisted from time to time. I say from time to time now because I've just ran into one computer running Outlook 2016 that it never persist the value unless my code explicitly calls the `Save` method on the `RDOMail` returned from `GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject`. Outlook really feels unpredictable on this part.